# Laravel Defining Complex Relationships

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relationship

I need help in defining relationships for the following tables

```
product
  id
  name

modifier
  id
  name

modifier_items
  id
  modifier_id
  name
  price

modifier_product
  id
  modifier_id
  product_id
```

One Product may have multiple Modifiers

Please help me define
 a relationship in Laravel that outputs the expected results

Expected Result in Product Model

> i.e Product::with([...])->get()

```
  id: 1,
  name: "Product name", // (Product name)
  modifiers: [
    {
      id: 1, // modifier_id
      name: "some name 1",
      items: [
        {
          id: 1, // modifier_item_id,
          name: "modifier name",
          price: 10
        },
        {
          id: 2, // modifier_item_id,
          name: "modifier name",
          price: 20
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "some name 2",
      items: [] // Collection of Modifier items
    },
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Model `Product.php`

```
public function modifiers()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Modifier::class, 'modifier_product'); // Modifier::class is Modifier Model and modifier_product is table name
}
```

Model `Modifier.php`

```
public function modifierItems()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ModifierItem::class); //modifier_items Model
}
```

You can retrive

```
Product::with('modifiers')->get(); //get product with modifiers
or
Product::with('modifiers.modifierItems')->get(); //get product with modifiers and modifier_items
```